# map<string, int> throws std::out_of_range when called from const function

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constants, stdmap

Noticing a peculiar behavior when using std::map from a function that doesn't change the state of its object:

```
std::map<std::string, int> _attribLocations;
...
int ProgramInfo::getAttribLocation(const std::string& name) const
{
    return _attribLocations.at(name);
}
```

When I call this function, passing a string literal, the lookup throws out_of_range exception:

```
auto index = info.getAttribLocation("v_position");
```

I noticed there are two versions of at(), one that uses a const_iterator, and one that doesn't:

```
mapped_type& at(const key_type& _Keyval)
        {   // find element matching _Keyval
        iterator _Where = _Mybase::lower_bound(_Keyval);
        if (_Where == _Mybase::end()
            || _Mybase::_Getcomp()(_Keyval, _Mybase::_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
            _Xout_of_range("invalid map<K, T> key");
        return (_Where->second);
        }

    const mapped_type& at(const key_type& _Keyval) const
        {   // find element matching _Keyval
        const_iterator _Where = _Mybase::lower_bound(_Keyval);
        if (_Where == _Mybase::end()
            || _Mybase::_Getcomp()(_Keyval, _Mybase::_Key(_Where._Mynode())))
            _Xout_of_range("invalid map<K, T> key");
        return (_Where->second);
        }
    };
```

It seems like the part that's causing it to throw is:

`_Mybase::_Getcomp()(_Keyval, _Mybase::_Key(_Where._Mynode()`))

I didn't really debug any deeper than this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

I'm sure that the key being passed does exist in the map (from inspecting the map with a debugger). Could it be a bug in the map implementation, or maybe I'm missing something about comparing strings?

Comment: I'm using VS2015 Update 2 and cannot reproduce this behavoir. Have you tried reproducing this in a minimal example project?

Comment: You gotta show us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, stupid mistake! It turns out the keys stored in my map were padded with terminating characters (they were thousands of characters long, mostly '\0'). I was passing in string literals like "gl_position", and the lookup was actually not finding anything. I was using [] operator in the non-const function, which returns the default int (0), which is the one I was expecting anyway. but at() failed to find the value, and threw. Here's what was happening:

```
class A
{
public:

    A()
    {
        char* foo = (char*)malloc(40000);
        foo[0] = 'f';
        foo[1] = 'o';
        foo[2] = 'o';       

        for (int i = 3; i < 40000; i++)
            foo[i] = '\0';

        std::string fooStr(foo, 40000);

        map[fooStr] = 5;
    }


    int getAttribLocation(const std::string name) 
    {
        return map[name];
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, int> map;
};

int main()
{
    A instance;

    auto x = instance.getAttribLocation("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

The confusion came from switching between [] and at(), because I couldn't use [] in a constant function.

Comment: And you understand that you can fix this by just doing `std::string fooStr(foo);` right? That is, don't pass a length argument to the constructor.

Comment: Ah, yep, that's better than trimming manually.